# How to add square tiles to leaflet map with hovering effect?

Tags: javascript, css, gis, leaflet, tiles-game

I want to split my map into tiles/territories. So i've prepared another layer showing squares. But this layer is full of .png image files so there is no data/object for this squares.

I've also tried to draw squares with leaflet's geometry objects. But it causing performance issues, there is times to show 500+ squares.

If you develop something like that what method would you prefer? UTFGrid? GeoJSON/Geometry?  Or maybe any other better solution?

**UPDATE:**

Actually i don't want to get data belongs to square's territory i just want to change the square's color somehow i mean somehow i want to highlight that area maybe i can create a rectangle on the fly when user mouseover.

And im trying avoid to use UTFGrid for just highlighting. But I want to ensure the UTFGrid is the only way or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the exact reason that UTFGrid was created!  [This site](https://github.com/nvkelso/geo-how-to/wiki/Adding%20interactivity) links to the tutorial that I used when learning UTFGrid, and it is solid.

Updated after your update:

MarkerCluster might have the look/feel you are going after, they basically paint a polygon onto the map layer.  You can check the source [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/f4e7845c8a79730d093fcd1910015e9146ff1b7a/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js#L610), and here's a relevant snippet:

```
    _showCoverage: function (e) {
            var map = this._map;
            if (this._inZoomAnimation) {
                    return;
            }
            if (this._shownPolygon) {
                    map.removeLayer(this._shownPolygon);
            }
            if (e.layer.getChildCount() > 2 && e.layer !== this._spiderfied) {
                    this._shownPolygon = new L.Polygon(e.layer.getConvexHull(), this.options.polygonOptions);
                    map.addLayer(this._shownPolygon);
            }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've just updated my question. So actually im trying to avoid to use utfgrid (i don't know how to generate) for just changing a color or somehow highlighting that area.

Comment: Ok so you want something that highlights exactly like markercluster? http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html